# The Composite doesn't scroll when its inner components enlarge in swt

Tags: java, dynamic, eclipse-plugin, scroll, swt

I created a class extending the SWT Composite class and there is a dynamically expanding Section in it. When a button is clicked, the size (height) of the section is increased. ***I want to increase the size of my composite too when the section is exceeding the size of the composite.*** But in my code it doesn't happen. I also set the style when calling the super constructor, but no success.

```
super(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
```

Following is the complete code of the class.

```
public class composite2 extends Composite {

private final FormToolkit toolkit = new FormToolkit(Display.getCurrent());

//constructor
public composite2(final Composite parent, int style) {
    super(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener() {
        public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e) {
            toolkit.dispose();
        }
    });
    toolkit.adapt(this);
    toolkit.paintBordersFor(this);
    setLayout(new FormLayout());

    final Section section1 = toolkit.createSection(this, Section.TWISTIE
            | Section.TITLE_BAR);

    final FormData fd_section1 = new FormData();

    fd_section1.top = new FormAttachment(0, 10);
    fd_section1.left = new FormAttachment(0, 10);
    fd_section1.right = new FormAttachment(100, -10);
    fd_section1.bottom = new FormAttachment(0, 122);

    section1.setLayoutData(fd_section1);
    toolkit.paintBordersFor(section1);
    section1.setText("LogicalPeopleGroups");
    section1.setBackground(SWTResourceManager
            .getColor(SWT.COLOR_INFO_BACKGROUND));

    final Button btnNewButton = new Button(section1, SWT.NONE);
    toolkit.adapt(btnNewButton, true, true);
    section1.setTextClient(btnNewButton);
    btnNewButton.setText("+");

    btnNewButton.setLocation(30, 1);
    btnNewButton.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
        int incre=122+10;
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            btnNewButton.setText("-");
            System.out.println("clickedddddd");
            fd_section1.bottom = new FormAttachment(0,incre);
            incre+=10;
            section1.setExpanded(true);
        }

    });
    }
}
```

I currently work in ubuntu 12.04 LTS and using WindowBuilder plugin for eclipse. And I use this class to set the UI of a page of a multi page editor in a eclipse plugin. I use following code for that where it creates a object of my composite2 class.

```
Composite composite = new composite2(getContainer(), SWT.NONE);
int index = addPage(composite);
setPageText(index, "Properties");
```

I tried using, ScrolledComposite class instead of Composite, but it was not successful. So can anybody tell me how to do what I want.